# To search either of two strings in text file using findstr and echo errorlevel

Tags: batch-file, findstr

I need to search either of strings "HTS 3.0 678 NO" or "HTS 5.0 679 OK" from the text file abc.txt and echo errorlevel when either one of the strings are found using batch file . I tried the below code snippet but errorlevel is 1 even though "HTS 5.0 679 OK" is found.

```
 >nul findstr /C:"HTS 3.0 678 NO" /C:"HTS 5.0 679 OK" "C:\abc.txt"
    if %errorlevel% EQU 0 (
    echo "Success"
    ) else (
    echo "failure"
   )
```

Please advise how to achieve using findstr

Comment: I can't replicate the errorlevel output you are receiving.  Your code and input example produces **Success** in my tests.

Comment: Your code works, given it is not placed within a parenthesised block. Though it could be simplified to this: `> nul findstr /C:"HTS 3.0 678 NO" /C:"HTS 5.0 679 OK" "C:\abc.txt" && (echo Success) || (echo Failure)` (which could even be placed within `(`/`)`; see [here](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) for `&&`/`||`)